# Map App crashing when starting up

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-manifest

I followed DrFraser's tutorial for a Google maps tutorial and followed all the steps. However, the maps crash as soon as I start it. My androidmanifest.xml is below. I think there is some problem in the  part. Please look through.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="biki.mapsdemo.com"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
     android:minSdkVersion="11"
     android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission 
     android:name="biki.mapsdemo.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature"   />

<uses-permission android:name="biki.mapsdemo.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permssion.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

 <uses-feature 
     android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
     android:required="true"  />

 <application
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

     <meta-data 
         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
         android:value="AI----1QMTtRP7wkMOnCPswB84MzenVib9D70"
         />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your full logcat.

Comment: I dont have a AVD . I just run the application so that .apk is generated and I email myself that .apk file. That might be the cause? @PG_Android

Comment: No Nothing like that. But without run into your device or in emulator how did you notice which error are you getting??? So first run your app and post logcat.

Comment: @PG_Android I run the .apk on my real android device. So no logcat as of now. Should I setup a AVD and run it and post the logcat?

Comment: Your app stopped with this message "Unfortunately Map Stopped"??

Comment: yes you are right @PG_Android

Comment: So you have to post logcat otherwise without it i am not able to give you any kind of answer.

Comment: @user3934169 connect your phone to PC and debug your app and post logcat error, we can't help you without seeing your error

Comment: should I post the full logcat or only specifics? @PG_Android

Comment: @user3934169 Full logcat but with specific error

Comment: 09-29 11:23:12.705: E/ACDB-LOADER(266): Error: Sending ACDB AFE result = -1 errno=22
09-29 11:23:12.705: E/ACDB-LOADER(266): Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
09-29 11:23:12.755: E/BluetoothPhoneService(1181): handlePreciseCallStateChange: CdmaCallsSwapped = false
09-29 11:23:12.755: E/BluetoothPhoneService(1181): Could not get a handle on Connection object for the call
09-29 11:23:12.755: E/BluetoothPhoneService(1181): swap; CONF -> THRWAY ; isGeneric = false
09-29 11:23:12.755: E/BluetoothPhoneService(1181): callsSwitched : false

Comment: @user3934169 Mate, this is useless.

Comment: @PG_Android Sorry for that but the character limit is too less to copy and paste the entire logcat here. I'm new to Android so please bear with me. Please tell me what to do and I'll follow up. thankyou.

Comment: from command prompt run `adb shell logcat -c` to clear existing log , and then run your app, and again `adb shell logcat -d` to dump the new log messages. Update your question with the stack trace from logcat.